# Macadamia nuts! Who or what am I?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

Macadamia nuts!

Use the above clue to find my identity. You must explain the relevance of the clue and the hint.

Hint: I publicise Apple products.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the answer is

> I AM A MAC AD

which is

> an anagram ("nuts") of MACADAMIA. (And, obviously, it does indeed roughly mean "I publicise Apple products".)

Comment: Correct! That was quick.